# Error - ListNode does not name a type

Tags: c++, struct

In the .h file,

```
  7 using namespace std;
  8 
  9 class DataStructure {
 10     private:
 11         struct ListNode {
 12             int item;
 13             ListNode *next;
 14         };
 15         int size;
 16         ListNode *head;
 17 
 18     public:
 19         DataStructure(int N, vector<int> elements);
 20 
 21         ListNode* findnode(int index);
 22         void move(int index, int siz);
 23 
 24 };
```

In the .cpp file

```
 26 DataStructure::ListNode* DataStructure::findnode(int index) {
 27     ListNode *start;
 28     start=head;
 29 
 30     for (int i=1; i<index; i++)
 31         start=start->next;
 32 
 33     return start;
 34 }
```

@line 26 in .cpp, error: ListNode does not name a type.
I'm quite sure I did everything right. Annoying. 
EDIT: Following a reply, I updated my code.

```
DataStructure.cpp:26:26: error: prototype for 'DataStructure::ListNode* DataStructure::findnode(int)' does not match any in class 'DataStructure'
DataStructure.h:17:18: error: candidate is: DataStructure::ListNode DataStructure::findnode(int)
```

Comment: Please declare your constructor using a const vector<int>& instead of a vector<int>. Vector copying is not optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListNode` is defined inside `DataStructure` so you have to say `DataStructure::ListNode` for the return type of the `findnode` function.

Comment: Nope doesn't work... Edited question to try your idea

Comment: You appear not to have shown us the real code as submitted to the compiler. Line 21 in your question shows `findnode` returning a pointer, but the compiler message indicates the compiler saw `ListNode` (not pointer) as the return type.

Comment: In general it's not good to change to posted code with corrections as then the question and posted answers don't make sense. Rather add the changes as addenda to the question.

Comment: oh. Thanks for the tip steve. I checked the question again. it is exactly as shown, what I compiled. I also double checked my directory and file names.

Comment: Well, it's still the case that line 21 doesn't match the compiler error message, implying your posted code isn't what you submitted to the compiler. Also the line numbers in the compiler message do not match.

Comment: This is mind boggling... I give up... Thanks for your help anyway. Not sure why my compiler is effing things up.

Answer (score 0):

you should wrote a function to fill up your `struct` call it then define `findNone`.